# Rails - using enum in a .where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I am using enum on a model:

`enum status: [:pending, :approved]`

I have a uniqueness validation in the model that looks like this:

```
validates :item_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id, conditions: -> { where(status: :approved) }, message: "You already have this item." }
```

This doesn't work.  It will only work if I change `:approved` to `1`.  I'm confused as to why I can't use the status name here when I can do something like `Item.first.update_attributes(status: :approved)` and it works fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the enum value from the model like so:

`where(status: Model.statuses[:approved])`

Instead of just the symbol. That way the enum helper method for `statuses` will pass the integer value of the enum which will make the filter work. The enum values are actually stored as integers in the DB not as the string representation of the symbols.

Comment: So just to clarify when is it that I can and can't just use the symbol?  Setting the attribute using the symbol seems to work just fine.

Comment: When you use enum rails internally creates a getter and setter method with the name of the enum and the getter will always return the string key for the corresponding integer value, when you call the setter and pass the symbol rails will lookup for the integer value and set it and that is what gets persisted on the database (the integer) so when you are querying activerecord will try to filter an integer column in the db with a string which won't work of course. So, long story short, query with the value that is returned on the enum pluralized hash, and assign with a symbol if you like.

Comment: Just looked at the documentation and it seems that the current unstable version of rails now allows for symbol within queries: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: Using enum automatically provides [scopes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.6/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) matching the enum on the Model, so the whole `where(...)` could also be replaced by just `Model.approved`.

Comment: @dlauzon Yes but in this particular case what the OP wanted was to filter within a validation conditional so am not sure if using a scope there works.

Comment: how can I wrote it as a link path?